# A challenging visual puzzle

Tags: visual, steganography

Here's a puzzle that I created. The end result is a number.
[image: the puzzle]

Comment: https://hackflag.org/forum/showthread.php?tid=3732

Comment: Yes, I've posted the same puzzle before on that forum a few months ago, but finding this stackexchange site reminded me and led me to post it here as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The puzzle represents:

> Pi 3.1415926535...

I ran the image through a [magic eye finder](http://magiceye.ecksdee.co.uk/) and got this mess:

> [image: Messy Image]

I cleaned that up to get this:

> [image: Cleaned Image]

And inverted the colors to get this:

> [image: QR Code]

Which is a QR code that translates to the following text:

> 143353-486602

Or, in raw bytes, this:

> 20 68 31 11 43 93 9c 96 e2 1c 10 00 ec 11 ec 11 ec 11 ec

---

All hail Len! I had been trying to figure out which coordinate system to use. I found Almere in OP's profile but had no idea the Dutch had their own coordinate system. God help the American education system...

Here's the final piece as posted by Len (if you +1 me, then +1 Len, too):

> The final number is pi
>  
>  From the clue on the OP's profile page, the numbers (143353-486602) are coordinates for the Dutch RD (Rijks-Driehoek) system. Using this site for conversion provides WGS84 coordinates of (52.367180,5.216201) which is in the city of Almere, Netherlands. With Google satellite, the coordinates are exactly at the number 3 as shown in this photo.
>  
>  [image: Final Solution]
>  You can tell by the rest of the digits that, for some reason, pi is printed in giant digits on the asphalt. From the other forum that OP posted in, he was looking for the first 10 digits. In that case, it's `3.1415926536` or, if you go out to my favorite digit of pi, it's `3.14159265358979323846264338327950`

Comment: You're halfway, and mostly on the right track.

Comment: That's only halfway? Argh. Can you at least confirm if my QR code is right? Cleaning up the original was a pain and there were some gray areas that I couldn't be sure if they were supposed to be black or white.

Comment: Yes, the fact that you were able to actually scan the QR would be enough information. Also, your first conclusion is almost completely correct. My profile could actually contain an (unintenden) hint for the next step.

Comment: The number could also be pi, which is what the rest of the string of numbers is.

Comment: I had a look at the translated forum that you found, and the coordinates would be Dutch like Len suggests. The forum also said that the first one to get 10 digits would get an apple pie, so the answer is pi for 100% sure. @Peetz0r

Comment: "God help the American education system..."
Well, I never learned this at school, either :p

Comment: That was so AWESOME! O_o

Answer (score 12):

If this is correct, feel free to add in to the first answer.  Continuing with the excellent work by Engineer Toast, I think this completes the second part of the puzzle:

> The final number is **3**
>
>  From the clue on the OP's profile page, the numbers (143353-486602) are coordinates for the Dutch RD (Rijks-Driehoek) system.
>  Using this [site](http://www.regiolab-delft.nl/?q=node/36) for conversion provides WGS84 coordinates of (52.367180,5.216201) which is in the city of Almere, Netherlands.
>  With Google satellite, the coordinates are exactly at the number 3 as shown in this photo.
>
>  [image: AlmerePhoto]