# Lots of dull colors!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, steganography

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZHkN.png]

Note: I created this puzzle. Good Luck!

Comment: https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin This is a steganography all parts of the puzzle are in the image

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin There are many puzzles like this on stackexchange already https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110432/a-heavenly-puzzle?rq=1 https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/109591/champion-with-a-smirk?rq=1 https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106183/cheers-people?rq=1 https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9533/a-challenging-visual-puzzle?rq=1 https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/115368/its-all-just-noise-to-me?rq=1

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin While your enthusiasm is to be commended, the linked meta post isn't *always* relevant to puzzles where the user is tasked with working out something enigmatic with minimal information provided by the OP. It certainly applies to character-string ciphers just dumped on the page with no clue towards the decryption method (they really are no fun to solve), but in this particular case the OP has actually provided a hint in the shapes chosen to be used within the illustration (see the checkmarked answer). Thanks for being on the ball, but I think we can let this one slide :)

Comment: Not sure if its dependant on scroll speed/monitor refresh speed or what, but that image (seems to) shakes like crazy when I scroll up and down.

Comment: Thats odd, I am not experiencing that but maybe try viewing it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZHkN.png)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The colors are

> in the shape of hexagons.

This suggests

> we look at the hex values of the colors.

They are

> 43 6F 6E 67 72 61 74 73 20 79 6F 75 20 73 6F 6C 76 65 64 20 74 68 69 73 20 70 75 7A 7A 6C 65 20 3A 2D 29 2E

Those look like

> ASCII values

They are

> Congrats you solved this puzzle :-).

Comment: Congrats you solved this puzzle :-).

Comment: Just for completion: rot13(gur gvgyr vf nyfb n ovg bs n uvag nf nyy gur inyhrf ner qhyy orpnhfr nfpvv inyhrf bayl tb hc gb 7N (yrff guna unys oevtugarff))

Comment: But then, rot13(gur ETO inyhrf ercerfrag NFPVV pbqrf ertneqyrff bs jung onfr gurl'er abgngrq va, fb gur pyhr sbe "urk" pyhrf fbzrguvat veeryrinag.)

Comment: @RosieF rot13(Abg ernyyl gur urkntba vf zrnag gb or gnxra abgvpr bss orpnhfr n urkntba unf gur fnzr cersvk nf urknqrpvzny. V jvyy nffhzr lbh qvq abg qb lbhe bja erfrnepu orpnhfr vs jr sbyybjrq lbhe zrgubq jr jvyy trg n zvk bs yrggref, ahzoref naq punenpgref va n enaqbz beqre.)